# how to select with group by user in postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have two tables user and messages. I want to select user's messages by time and group by userId. I use postgresql and I want to select only one message that time has max Here are my tables and sql queries:

```
 users                                   messages
id name surname e-mail                  id userId    title    time  token
1   joe  joe     bla@hotmail.com          1    1      title1   null     1
                                          1    1      title2   null     2
                                          1    1      title3   null     3
                                          1    1      title4   null     4

 select *,max(m.time) from users u join messages m on u.id=m.userId group by m.userId
```

I get sql error when select messages group by userId

Comment: I think some clarification is needed - what exactly is it you would like to see and what is the database you are using (SQL Server, Oracle, DB2, MySQL, Postgresql, ...)

Comment: I want to select only one message that has max time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're looking for this :

```
select *
  from messages m
 where (m.userId, m.time) in 
(
 select m.userId,max(m.time) 
   from users u join messages m 
     on u.id=m.userId 
  group by m.userId
);

id  userid  title   time                        token
--  ------  ------  --------------------------- -----
1   1       title2  2018-09-01T13:37:21.075024Z 2
```

[***SQL Fiddle Demo***](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/df36a/5)

Comment: thank you for solution. this is exactly I am looking for

Comment: nice to see you here :))